# Where is Session::put() data stored using database session driver in Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, database, session, laravel

I'm currently using the [database session driver](http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-drivers) to store my sessions in Laravel.

I understand that the user sessions are stored in the database, but does the data from a Session::put get stored?

For example:

```
Session::put('userID', $user->id);
```

Where is the data about the userID being stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under default settings your sessions are stored in a table called 'sessions' in your default database connection.

Each session will have a payload which contains all sorts of data, but your userID will be in the payload for your session's row somewhere.

Comment: Fantastic.  I did a bit more looking into it and it looks like the payload is a Base64 encoded JSON type file.  I decoded it and ended up finding s:6:"userID";s:1:"1"; inside of it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't realise you wanted the dirty technical details. Glad I led you there anyway I guess.